# Cannot run cron job for a php script

Tags: command-line, scripts, php, cron

I want to run a php script using cron job on localhost. My script is located at:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/rrugd/myscript.php
```

Since opt is under root, I tried adding the cron job for root, as well as normal user, but it is not executing. This is the cron job for executing the php script every 2 minutes:

```
*/2 * * * * php /opt/lampp/htdocs/rrugd/myscript.php
```

My script is basically meant to truncate a table from the database. It will actually be happening at midnight, so the actual variables of cron job will change to

```
00 00 * * * php /path/to/script.php
```

But for testing I've used every two minutes. Ive searched on the internet, and AU, but I cannot get it to run.
I saw something related to setting a PATH but I didn't understand what is to be done exactly in that method.

Also, I would like to specify that the PHP script `myscript.php` DID NOT execute on CLI with the PHP command, however it does execute when executed or called through the browser on localhost!

PHP Information:

```
some@somepc$: php -v
PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.2 (cli) (built: Feb 28 2014 20:06:05) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: If you've installed php, then try `*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/rrugd/myscript.php` instead & let me know whether it works.. or the location of where `php` is located.. :)

Comment: @AzkerMohamed that didnt work either! :(

Comment: is that php5 you've installed?? if so make sure you've installed php5-cli using `sudo apt-get install php5-cli` in order execute using terminal commands. And then you can try replacing `php` into `php5`. Let me know how it goes

Comment: @AzkerMohamed yes its php5, i have php-cli installed and i tried replacing php with php5, and it still doesnt work :(

Comment: Firstly, could you please edit your question and post the output for `php -v` & `whereis php`... also as an alternative you can try to place your php script in localhost `www` dir (or htdocs or whatever) & try to call it as a url `*/2 * * * * wget -q http://localhost//myscript.php`. Let me try to make it more clear after looking at the outputs.

Comment: @AzkerMohamed yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah!!! that worked! omfg i cant tell you how happy i am! thankyou sooooo much! the wget method worked!! please post it as an answer...i shall accept it!

Comment: I'm not sure why php didn't work for you as it worked for me. Well another guess made me to post php script using URL. I'd say wget is one little command which helped me so many ways. BTW, I have posted it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming its **php5**; There are instance of using php into a cronjob. You may try one of these by following;

- In order to use `php5` in terminal you will need `php5 cli` installed. First, check whether `php5 & cli` functionality is available. for that;

```
johan@ubusrv:~$ php -v 
PHP 5.2.4-2ubuntu5.3 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Jul 23 2008 06:44:49) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2007 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.2.0, 
Copyright (c) 1998-2007 Zend Technologies
```

The command displays that your php5 version along with php5 (cli) installed. If not, install it using the following command;

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

- Once installed you can either add `php` or its binary path to the cronjob as below;

using **php** or **php5**

```
*/2 * * * * php /opt/lampp/htdocs/rrugd/myscript.php
```

using **php** binary path

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/rrugd/myscript.php
```

You may also use below commands to find where your **php/php5** path is;

```
johan@ubusrv:~$ which php 
/usr/bin/php 

johan@ubusrv:~/cli$ whereis php 
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz 

johan@ubusrv:~/cli$ type -a php 
php is /usr/bin/php
```

- Elsewhere, if you need to call a php script using URL; you can simply use **lynx**, **curl** or **wget**. Make sure you've placed your php script within the `www` or `public_html` directory and call the path properly on the cronjob.

```
*/2 * * * * wget -q http://localhost//myscript.php
```

**More on:** [PHP Cron Job: How to Execute PHP Script Using Crontab in Linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/)