# php /var/www/html/*.php is not working in terminal which is open from Menu php *.php is working in terminal which is open inside php holding folder

Tags: cron, php7

I want to run a PHP script from cron. I setup cron with:

```
*/1 * * * * php  /var/www/html/cron/cron_job.php
```

And I can see it in `crontab -u root -l`, but the job is not executed. It also doesn't work when I run the command directly from the command line like this:

```
<?php  /var/www/html/cron/cron_job.php
```

I tried many answers related to cron but nothing worked. For example:

```
/usr/local/bin /var/www/html/cron/cron_job.php
/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/cron/cron_job.php
sudo php -f /var/www/html/cron/cron_job.php
```

The testing php script (`cron_job.php`) is:

```
php file_put_contents  ('test.txt',"test content\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

File permissions are all OK and it is working when run in the browser or when opening a terminal in `/var/www/html/cron/` and running `php cron_job.php`.

As requested in the comments, if I append `2> /tmp/php.log` to `php /var/www/html/cron/cron_job.php` use  a script with a syntax error and try to run (`php /var/www/html/cron/cron_job.php 2> /tmp/php.log`) from menu terminal, then the error log gets the error message.

Comment: You say that the command doesn't work when you run it from a terminal. Then why do you expect it to work if you run from cron? Please [edit] your question and clarify. Assuming that's just a typo and it does work from the terminal, we need to know what the script does. Can you show us the script? Even better, can you show us a minimal example script that reproduces the problem? Finally, add `2> /tmp/php.log` to the end of your cron line and tell us i) if a file called `/tmp/php.log` is created and ii) if there is anything in that file.

Comment: Does the user "php" exist?

Comment: @RajeshKeladimath if I am not mistaken php is not user. it is programming name. I refered so many like this... http://askubuntu.com/questions/430509/cannot-run-cron-job-for-a-php-script

Comment: @terdon *You say that the command doesn't work when you run it from a terminal.* - I open terminal from start menu and try run `php  /var/www/html/cron/cron_job.php` which is not working. But I open terminal inside `/var/www/html/cron/` and try run `php cron_job.php` is working.
I append `2> /tmp/php.log` with `php  /var/www/html/cron/cron_job.php` is php.log is empty :(

Comment: @RajeshKeladimath this isn't `/etc/crontab` where there is a specific user field. This is a normal, user lever cron (just happens to be the root user's) so there is no username column.

Comment: @Naga please **[edit]** to add new information, don't put it in the comments. That clarification is very important, it needs to be in your question. However, if a `/tmp/php.log` file is created and is empty, then the script ran with no errors. We can't help more unless you show us the script.

Comment: @terdon Thank you for your commands. I edited my question as much as more info. The script is very simple. Just append some text in a file which is in the same directory.  Yes. You are right. I put some script with error and try run from menu terminal then the error log got error message. will update this with my question shortly.

Comment: @terdon thanks. I was unaware of user cron tab. I have removed my answer.

Comment: @RajeshKeladimath in general, you *always* want to use the user's crontab. There are very few cases where you would need the global one. In fact, I don't think I've ever used it in almost 20 years of using Linux. Certainly not on my personal machine, anyway.

Comment: @terdon thank you for your suggestion. I will avoid this habit in future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your script is almost certainly running and creating your file. It's just not creating it where you expect it to be. You are not using any path in your script, you just use a file name. This means that the file will be created in the directory the script is running in.

That's why, when you move into a specific directory and run the script there, you think it works. Because the file is created in the directory you ran it in and so you can see it. By default, `cron` runs in the home directory of the user running it. Since this is root's crontab (which, by the way, is a bad idea), the file will be created in `/root`. So, go check:

```
sudo ls /root/test.txt
```

So, next time, give your script a full path instead of just a file name:

```
<?php file_put_contents  ('/path/to/test.txt',"test content\n",FILE_APPEND); ?>
```

Now, the file will be created in `/path/to`.

Answer (score 6):

By default Cron jobs are executed in the user's home directory. While in your script is not provided path where the output file to be saved, it will be saved into the directory where the script is executed.

In your PHP scrip the path to the file `test.txt` is missing. You can set it as absolute value as it is described in @terdon's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/875997/566421), or you can provide it as relative path (with proper origin). For example, if `test.txt` shuld be located in the same directory as `cron_job.php`, the content of your script should become something like as this:

```
<?php 
    $path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)); 
    file_put_contents  ("$path/" . 'test.txt',"test content\n",FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to change the script you could change the Cron job in this way:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /var/www/html/cron/ && php cron_job.php
```