# Ubuntu 16.04 FileNotFoundError when the program is run from another folder

Tags: 16.04, bash

I have created a program that uses additional files for example form.ui and when I run the program from a directory of the program, all is ok, but when I run from another folder I get an `FileNotFoundError`, how can I fix it? I would be grateful for any advice.

```
v@v-System-Product-Name:/path/AppName$ ./app
```

Works.

```
v@v-System-Product-Name:~$ /path/AppName/app

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or catalog: 'form.ui'
```

Comment: Dumb question: Does the file exists in the other folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add path to the file before its name, in the script. It looks that your file - `form.ui` - is in the same directory where the script is located. So you need to get the current location of the script and put this path before the file name.

For example, let's assume you just want to print (on the screen) the content of the file `form.ui`, and:

- you using [**bash**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/6543935). The script must looks like:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
  cat "$DIR/form.ui"
  ```
- you using [**php**](https://askubuntu.com/a/876000/566421). The script must looks like:

  ```
  <?php
      $DIR = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
      echo file_get_contents("$DIR/".'form.ui');
  ?>
  ```

Where the variable `$DIR` contains the path to your script.

Comment: I had not seen that question is tagged with `Bash`.